# How to fix 'error in Eclipse Neon while opening first time'?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

See the error [image]Work space problem while start up

Comment: it points you to a log file, Look into that log file and see what is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you just want to look in the log files?

However, delete this from your workspace:

```
.../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
```

Also please delete your metadata folder. There are many issues with that

Comment: After deleting too! Problem is still! Please help me

Comment: Could you please add the log files to your question?

Comment: Are you using a Java 9 ea build?

Comment: Yes I am using Java 9!

Comment: Which eclipse build are you using?

Comment: If you got an outdated version please add this after the "-vmargs line"
: "-addmods
java.se.ee"

Comment: How Can I add this plug in?

Comment: Just go to eclipse.ini and search for "-vmargs line". Add "-addmods java.se.ee"

Comment: "-vmargs line" should I replace this one "-addmods java.se.ee"

Comment: Do not replace. Just add it

Comment: Can you help me with Team Viewer?

Comment: Please mail me if you free : moreprathameshmore@hotmail.com

Comment: Yes I will. But please send me the eclipse.ini again (the new one)

Comment: Where located this file?